# Laravel Spatie can() always returning false but hasPermissionTo() works

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

I'm trying to create permissions and roles for users in a Laravel Project using Spatie creating permissions and assigning them to roles and then users works fine, but when checking for permission using `can` it always returns false even when the permission is assigned to the role, but `hasPermissionTo` works as expected.

Comment: try to run `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: @MohammadEdrisRaufi worked like a charm! can you add as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as we discussed on the comments sometimes you have to clear your cache try running

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```